# QuillJS selection-change caches results for some reason

Tags: javascript, typescript, quill

I have:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if (quill) {
            quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(documentContent);
            quill.on('text-change', () => {
                setDocumentContent(quill.root.innerHTML);
            });

            quill.on('selection-change', (range, oldRange, source) => {
                console.log(documentState?.predictionStatus, range, oldRange, source);
            })

        }
    }, [quill]);
```

But the `documentState.predictionStatus` stays at it's original value. I think maybe because the value is cached somehow?

Any way to resolve?

Thanks!

Comment: Where does `documentState` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your code look like this ?

```js
    const [documentState, setDocumentState] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        if (quill) {
            quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(documentContent);
            quill.on('text-change', () => {
                setDocumentContent(quill.root.innerHTML);
            });

            quill.on('selection-change', (range, oldRange, source) => {
                console.log(documentState?.predictionStatus, range, oldRange, source);
            })

        }
    }, [quill]);
```

You are trying to access  `documentState?.predictionStatus` inside the handler function of `quill.on` which will likely to cause error since the function you pass to `quill.on` only remember the value original of `documentState` (because of `closure`)

To fix this, `useRef` instead for `documentState`

```js
    const documentRef = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (quill) {
            quill.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(documentContent);
            quill.on('text-change', () => {
                setDocumentContent(quill.root.innerHTML);
            });

            quill.on('selection-change', (range, oldRange, source) => {
                console.log(documentRef.current?.predictionStatus, range, oldRange, source);
            })

        }
    }, [quill]);

/// somewhere in you code update documentRef
documentRef.current = newValue
```